# Jenkins triggered mutiple same jobs with different parameters end up in only one job

Tags: jenkins

According to some previous questions, I wrote my stage of parallel compile task with different parameters. I hope it would call the same build job with different parameters, but it only launch one job.
The jenkinsfile is like

```
stage('compile'){
        steps{
            script{
                tasks = BUILD_TASKS.split(',')
                def jobs = [:]
                for (arg in tasks)
                {
                    arg_sub = arg.split('_')
                    sh "echo ${arg_sub}"
                    pub = arg_sub[0]
                    arc = arg_sub[1]
                    doc = arg_sub[2]
                    jobs["${pub}_${arc}_${doc}"] = {stage("${pub}_${arc}_${doc}") {retry(1){
                                                              build job: 'compile2', parameters: 
                                                              [
                                                              string(name: 'DOCKER_IMG', value: "xxx:${doc}"),
                                                              string(name: 'PUBLIC_CLOUD', value: pub),
                                                              string(name: 'ARCHITECTURE', value: arc)
                                                              ]}}}
                }
                
                parallel jobs
                }
            }
        }
```

And then I run this task. What I think it would do:

- Open multiple `compile2` tasks with different parameters

What it really does:

- Open only one `compile2` task, the log output is

```
[YES_amd_7u]Starting building: compile2 #27
[YES_amd_7u]Starting building: compile2 #27
[YES_arm_8u]Starting building: compile2 #27
[YES_arm_8u]Starting building: compile2 #27
....
```

And in this compile2 #27, it logged

```
Started by upstream project "AutoRelease" build number 49
Started by upstream project "AutoRelease" build number 49
Started by upstream project "AutoRelease" build number 49
Started by upstream project "AutoRelease" build number 49
....
```

What is the problem with my jenkinsfile?

---

In addition, if i write the different tasks separately, like

```
parallel{
   YES_amd_7u:{
      build job xxxxxx
   },
   YES_arm_7u:{
      build job xxxxxx
   }
}
```

it works and logs

```
[YES_amd_7u]Starting building: compile2 #31
[YES_amd_7u]Starting building: compile2 #32
[YES_arm_8u]Starting building: compile2 #33
[YES_arm_8u]Starting building: compile2 #34
....
```

Comment: When it launches 1 job, do you see the others getting put in the queue?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I should define the params as a variable, and use

```
def jobparams = [
                                                              string(name: 'DOCKER_IMG', value: "xxx:${doc}"),
                                                              string(name: 'PUBLIC_CLOUD', value: pub),
                                                              string(name: 'ARCHITECTURE', value: arc)
                                                              ]
println jobparams
jobs["${pub}_${arc}_${doc}"] = {stage("${pub}_${arc}_${doc}") {retry(1){
                                                              build job: 'compile2', parameters: params
                                                              ]}}}
```

I don't know why this works, maybe because the jobparam should be defined explicitly to get an assgined value?